# Getting last transaction from a table using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, join

I am working with LINQ and MS SQL using c#. I am facing a problem in fetching records. I have 2 tables as,
Sales
Transactions
Sales primary key is being referred by Transactions table.Data is like,
[image]

What I am trying to do is to fetch all the records with amount != 0. In this example, the result should include only Sales2 and Sales3, but not Sales1. Since Sales1 is closed.

I have written a query like,

```
List<Sales> lstSales = (from ccs in context.Sales
                        join transactions in context.Transactions 
                             on ccs.SALESID equals  transactions.SALESID            
                        where transactions .AMOUNT !=0 
                       select ccs).ToList();
```

It returns me all the 3 Sales records, because for 1 row against Sales1, amount !=0.

Please guide me to achieve the desired results.

Thanks in advance,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your query filter out the closed transactions, still you have > 0 transactions in the result so you still get the Sales1 Id.

Try this instead (it should work, though I haven't tested this);

```
IEnumerable<int> closedIds = context.Transactions.Where(t => t.Amount == 0).Select(t=> s.SalesId);
List<Sales> sales = context.Sales.Where(s => !closedIds.Contains(s.SalesId));
```

Another approach is (assuming you have an association between Sales and Transaction in the context);

```
List<Sales> sales = context.Sales.Where(s => !s.Transactions.Any(t=> t.Amount == 0));
```

Comment: I tried another approach similar to you, not sure which will execute faster:)  List<Sales> lstCCSales = (from ccs in context.Sales                                                                  where !(from t in context.Transactions                                                                          where t.AMOUNT == 0                                                                          select t.SALESID)                                                                         .Contains(ccs.SALESID)                                                                  select ccs).ToList();

Comment: You could run a SQL Profiler to see which is better. I believe there might be two different T-SQL Scripts generated for the approaches.

Answer (score -2):

Make use of one of these:

[Enumerable.Any](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb534972.aspx)
[Enumerable.All](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you please advice me in above query ?

Comment: although the links are usefull references, this doesn't answer the question of the OP

Comment: Look at the Enumerable.All page and scroll down to the Examples section. There is a Example that almost fits your scenario...

Comment: What question? The OP asked for guidance.